# How can I put some comment in yum installation list?

Tags: yum, backup, rpm, restore

Lets say I made a List of installed packages by:

```
rpm -qa > list
```

I want to use this list to re-install those Packages on another System, For Example By:

```
yum -y install $(cat list)
```

But I need to write some comments in that list, How can I prevent yum from trying to install that Comment lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that you have `#` at beginning of comment lines, so you can do:

```
yum -y install $(awk '!/^#/' list)
```

`!/^#/` cause `awk` to ignore any lines that start with `#`, print the rest.